# Can I run my selenium WebDriver code in another computer's chorme browser?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I created a java selenium project using maven on computer A and I am able to run tests there successfully.
What I want to do is to run it successfully also on computer B.
This is my code:

```
private static String currentDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");

public static final WebDriver getDriver(Browsers type){
    return driverMap.get(type).get();
}

private static final Supplier<WebDriver> chromeDriverSupplier = () -> {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", currentDirectory + File.separator + "chromedriver.exe");
    return new ChromeDriver();
```

Is there a reason why I am not able to run it on computer B?
Is computer B must have "chromedriver.exe" installed in the project directory or can I achieve it without downloading "chromedriver.exe"?

Thanks

Comment: Of course with this configuration, but you shouldn't set this property progammatically and rather pass it as argument when you run the test. Therefore it will be easy to adapt the path

Comment: Try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56758747/is-there-a-way-to-make-gecko-driver-usable-for-everyone-in-shared-code/], maybe it can help you

Answer (score 0):

You need to have chromedriver.exe in computer B as well.

Answer (score 0):

I used  WebdriverManager as suggested in the link provided and it solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible using selenium grid. Selenium Grid allows you to start a hub and node, then by using a remote webdriver to connect to these other machines to run tests. 
Here is the URL for the [documentation](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp)  
This will also allow you to achieve parallel execution of test cases.

Once you have this set up you will set your remote driver with the following code:

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteDriver(new URL(nodeAddress, capabilities);
```

Below is also the link to remote driver maven dependency:
[maven dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-remote-driver)